# SSL Handshake fatal error after Client Hello

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

I am trying to make an https call to a server signed by an internal CA. I couldn't get it working in spite of adding the root certificates in the truststore so I've set the trustManager to trust all certificates and disabled hostname verification for now.
`curl --insecure` call works.
With `-Djavax.net.debug=all`, the handshake fails after client hello

> *** ClientHello, TLSv1   ...   ...    main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2   main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure   main, called closeSocket()   main, handling exception:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure   main, called close()   main, called
>   closeInternal(true)

The stack trace is:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)

I am getting the SSL Context using

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS: I am using **java7**

Comment: A handshake failure would occur *before* certificate trust is verified.  Check TLS is enabled on both ends and that there is a common cipher suite.  Look at the logs on the server end, inspect the negotiation with wireshark.

Comment: Please run your client with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and post the results in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to my own question after 4 years.

I don't recall what the exact issue was but there is no single reason for handshake failure - most likely reason for why handshake failure occurs right after ClientHello would be that the client & server are not able to agree upon a common protocol or cipher suite for continuing the handshake.

The easiest option for debugging SSL issues like this is capturing the network traffic with tcpdump and analyzing it in Wireshark. We can inspect the ClientHello and  figure out what is the protocol being used, the cipher suites that it advertises support for etc.

Comment: Wireshark is great, but for Java `javax.net.debug` gives the same info and more. Yes handshake_failure can have many causes and yes in this situation protocol compatibility is likely, especially because j7 released in 2011 _implemented_ TLS1.1 and 1.2 but _disabled_ them in client by default because of compatibility issues, but within months the BEAST attack was published and many people responded by requiring 1.1 or higher, including in 2015 the payment-card industry council for all sites handling card payments (which is most).